# How do I smoothly update a GridView by updating the bound DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datatable, datasource

I have a `GridView` who's `DataSource` is set to a `DataTable`. The `DataTable` is updated by some backend logic every few seconds, at which point a delegate is called to refresh `GridView`.

Currently I am simply resetting the `DataSource`, but that causes a problem - it interrupts any ongoing edits in the grid view and makes the selection 'jump' to the top-left cell.

The update logic basically creates a new (identical with regard to columns and rows) `DataTable`.

Is there any standard way to do it without any drawbacks? Is my only option updating the current `DataSource` row by row, inserting values programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `BindingList` or some data source that supports change notification.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by many things in this question.  If you're using a `GridView`, and not a `DataGridView`, then you're either using ASP.NET, WPF, or .NET 1.1.  Which is it?

Next:  you're creating a new `DataTable` entirely?  Well of course the control's going to get reset when you reset the `DataSource`.  It doesn't know that the schema of your new `DataTable` is the same as the one it's replacing.  It's got to go through the columns and re-establish the bindings.

Also, of *course* it's losing the current row.  The current row belongs to the old `DataTable`, not the new one.

If you want a bound control to retain its state when you update the underlying data source, *update* the underlying data source, don't replace it with a new one.

Comment: I'm indeed using a DataGridView.
The new DataTable has the same schema, and is simply generated from some database and modified by some process.
Of course I know _why_ the row is lost. My question is how should I do it so I won't have to replace the DataTable...

Comment: Oh, and I have no idea how to update an existing DataTable using a new one (I'm reluctant to scan it field by field...)

Comment: Take a look at the DataTable.Merge method.  That may well do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do your updates happen on a background thread? I don't know if it will work in your scenario, but you could try this [threaded binding list](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/f12a3c5980567f06); see the example to see the worker merrily editing the grid.